# How to stop save button function running when certain tab is open

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, tabs

I have a page that displays a few different tabs.

```
<li id="liHeader"><a href="#tabHeader" title="Header">General</a></li>
<li id="liFooter"><a href="#tabNotesComments" id="tabNotes" title="Notes/History of Job">Notes (<%= NoOfNotes %>)</a></li>
<li runat="server" id="liDelivery" ><a href="#<%= tabDeliveryDbrief.ClientID %>" title="Delivery Dbrief">Delivery Dbrief</a></li>
```

Each tab has different functions. Above these tabs is a few buttons new, save, delete etc. In the save function, there is code that creates a note every time something is updated. For example "user A updated job at 12:48 PM". 
This save button is for any changes that are made in any tab that is opened. But when the tab 'Delivery Debrief' is open, I don't want this note to be created every time I updated something. In this tab the information gets updated a lot so there will be too many notes. 
So every time the save button is clicked this code is run:

```
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string Note = Job.Compare(oldJob, new Job(int.Parse(Request.QueryString["JobID"])), Mod);
    JobNote modNote = new JobNote
                      {
                      JobID = job.ID,
                      Company_ID = CurCompID,
                      Date = DateTime.Now,
                      Time = DateTime.Now,
                      Note = Note,
                      CreatedBy = CurrentUser.UserID,
                      CreatedByName = CurrentUser.Username,
                      NoteType = 1
                      };
    modNote.Create();
}
```

Is there a way to stop this code running when the delivery debrief tab is open? The notes still need to be created for the other tabs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot prevent clicking, but you can do it with 2 method:

1 - Make  your button as html button and call click on server side by ajax(Web services)

2 - You can set an attribute (like 'active=false') to your `li` and on clicking the tab set it to 'true'. Now on server side check this attribute(`liDelivery.Attributes["active"]`) if it was true, it mean tab is open and doesn't do any thing

```
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    if(liDelivery.Attributes["active"].ToString() == "false") return;
    string Note = Job.Compare(oldJob, new Job(int.Parse(Request.QueryString["JobID"])), Mod);
                                JobNote modNote = new JobNote
                                {
                                    JobID = job.ID,
                                    Company_ID = CurCompID,
                                    Date = DateTime.Now,
                                    Time = DateTime.Now,
                                    Note = Note,
                                    CreatedBy = CurrentUser.UserID,
                                    CreatedByName = CurrentUser.Username,
                                    NoteType = 1
                                };
                                modNote.Create();
}
```